# aapt.exe has stopped working and R.java cannot be resolved after adding Google Play Services library to an existing project

Tags: android, google-ad-manager

**I get the solution. Post the solution below. Thank you every one.**

I'm trying to add new google-play-services_lib in my old project,
due to which R.jave file is removed from the project. 
Also, as soon as i remove google-play-services_lib, i get my R.java file back.
minimum sdk version is 11.
I'm referring to following link:
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

I am following these steps to add library as a project ==>
 Right-click on My project -> Properties In Android->Library section click Add select recently added project -> Ok

then aapt.exe has stopped working and R.jave file is removed from the project

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: Muhammad Zaighum - tried cleaning project several times .. not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution :
I changed ( android:id="@+id/) to ( android:id="@id/) in each views from my all layouts and create a new resource file at res/values/ids.xml and provide its "name"

For example

step1: old_layout.xml

```
<EditText  android:id="@+id/amount"                       
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/submit"                       
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

new_layout.xml

```
<EditText  android:id="@id/amount"                       
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<Button android:id="@id/submit"                       
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

step2: res/values/ids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item type="id" name="amount" />
<item type="id" name="submit" />
</resources>
```

Step3: clean and run the project .

Thats all its work for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your **gen** and **bin** folders
2. Clean and build your project
3. Run your project

Answer (score 0):

check the build paths section of your project. Ensure the under the Order and Export tab, the google_play_services library is checked. Clean & refresh the project once. Also Check any error in your xml files.

Comment: which is your minimum sdk version

Comment: minimum sdk version is 11.